# How to create new jar file in Windows?

Tags: java, jar

I've made some changes for photocam.js and want to create a new primafaces.jar from my old primafaces.jar which I extracted.

What is the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the JAR file using 7-Zip and replace the files inside it directly.

Comment: Don't I need to compile and make .jar file again?

Comment: I understood that it was JavaScript, so I didn't think that you need to compile it first. To be on the safe side, you could check whether the original file inside the JAR is in plain text, or something compiled. And of course be sure to have a backup copy before modifying an original file.

Comment: Yes It is JavaScript file and you are right there is no need for compilation.